# RAD studio 10.3.3 could not create java virtual machine

Tags: java, android, rad-studio

I already checked the issue but i didn't found a solution.

I use RAD STUDIO 10.3.3 in Win 10/**64b** and i have installed java 1.8_171/**32b**

I try to create a new (sample) android application **32b** and it builds ok.

When i try to run it raises the error `could not create java virtual machine` followed by
`[Exec Error] EXEC(1): A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

and

`[Exec Error] The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" -genkey -v -keystore "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\debug.keystore" -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname "cn=Unnamed, ou=Mobile Organization, o=Embarcadero Technologies, l=San Francisco, s=California, c=US" -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000" exited with code 1.`

As i can see java.exe does not support parameter `-keypass` and all the others following it. Is this meaning something ?
Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found my mistake.

In tools/options/deployment/SDKmanager/Java/keytool location I had the (wrong value) java.exe instead of keytool.exe

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Default value point to java.exe.... so that is probably the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is this meaning something?"

Those arguments are for the `keytool` command not the `java` command.

See the [Keytool manual page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html).

If your sample Android app is actually trying to run `keytool`, it is doing it the wrong way.  However, I don't think we can help beyond that unless you share the code with us so that we can understand what it is trying to do.

Comment: I do : File/new/multidevice app-Delphi/blanc application/android 32b --> run --> error

Comment: I won't use keytool (no cryptografy needed). My RAD IDE does it. Is there a setting to avoid this ?